# Hibernate mapping to a self-referential, many-to-many map

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, orm

In my database I have a `Food` which has a many-to-many relationship with other ingredient `Foods`. This relationship is represented as such...

```
+=============Foods============+    +==========Ingredients===========+
| Id | Name      | Description |    | FoodId | IngredientId | Amount |
+==============================+    +================================+
| 1  | Ice Cream | ........... |    | 1      | 2            | 300    |
+------------------------------+    +--------------------------------+
| 2  | Milk      | ........... |
+------------------------------+
```

In the domain model, however, the most logical data structure would be a map of `Foods` and amounts. Ultimately, when I load in "Ice Cream" I need the map to contain all of the ingredient `Foods` (found through the ingredients table) along with the corresponding value, but I am having trouble figuring out how to do this.

```
@Entity
@Table(name="Foods")
public class Food {
  @Id 
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY) 
  @Column(name="Id")
  private int id;

  @Column(name="Name")
  private String name;

  @Column(name="Description")
  private String description;

  @ManyToMany ???
  private Map<Food, Integer> ingredients;
```

Comment: Did you try using a `@OneToMany` ?

Comment: @jbx I think `@ManyToMany` will end up being the base annotation, but the mapping seems more complicated. I guess the problem I am having is more to do with getting the *Food* object into the map based on the id from the ingredients table.

Comment: Mmm... i wouldn't approach it that way honestly. Check my rough sketch answer below, see if it makes sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would first create a new entity `Ingredient`, which has a composite key consisting of both foreign keys, together with the `amount` integer. You can use `Food` directly as your field types for both foreign keys.

Then in your `Food` entity you can add a `@OneToMany` `Set<Ingredient>` mapping the `id` to the `Ingredient`'s `foodId`. You will then be able to get all the `Ingredient` entries for one `Food` easily.

Comment: Will Hibernate be able to implicitly map a numeric `FoodId` to a `Food` object?

Comment: Yes, unless you have something weird going on.